# let background drawable be smaller than view

Tags: android, android-layout, background-image, drawable

How do I let or force a background drawable to be smaller than the view? Say I have an ImageView which a user clicks to take a photo. I want to place the ic_photo_camera icon as the background of the ImageView. But I don’t want the icon to stretch to fit the size of the ImageView: I want the icon to maintain its own size. How do I do this without using a combination of views? but rather just one view? For instance I can use A RelativeLayout and two ImageView to accomplish this. But I am wondering if there is an option for just one ImageView.

**update**

I think this is as good as a picture: this does it presently. But I don't want to use three views, I want to use one if I can.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:background="#eeeeee"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/container"
        android:layout_width="250dp"
        android:layout_height="150dp"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true">

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:scaleType="center"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_photo_camera_white_48dp" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/photo"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop" />
    </RelativeLayout>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/label"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/container"
        android:background="#FFFFFF"
        tools:text="This is the label to some image" />


</RelativeLayout>
```

[image]

Comment: can you post your xml

Comment: I have added a "picture" in xml form

Comment: sorry. I still can not understand your purpose, can you post the result image that you want to have

Comment: I did it again. With full layout and image

Comment: The entire view is just an item inside a ListView.

Comment: so you want to display a imageview above another imageview

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#eeeeee">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/container"
        android:layout_width="250dp"
        android:layout_height="150dp"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:scaleType="center"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_photo_camera_white_48dp"
        android:background="@drawable/bg"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/label"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/container"
        android:background="#FFFFFF"
        android:gravity="center"
        tools:text="This is the label to some image" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

and create bg.xml in your res/drawable:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<bitmap xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:gravity="clip_horizontal"
    android:src="@drawable/photo" />
```

@drawable/photo is what you wanna put into your old ImageView with id "photo". gravity can be changed to clip_vertical based on your image aspectRatio.

If your wanna dynamically set "photo", you can:

```
    ImageView iv_container = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.container);
    Drawable drawable = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.photo_2);
    ((BitmapDrawable)drawable).setGravity(Gravity.CLIP_HORIZONTAL);
    iv_container.setBackgroundDrawable(drawable);
```

Comment: Sorry for taking so long to respond. I haven't hand another opportunity to return to that section of the project.

Answer (score 0):

hi，could you show a picture which you want to display, i can not hardly understand what you say. i try you can use the scaleType attribute of imageView, it has center, fixXY as so on. I appreciate it could help you.

Comment: added full layout and image